# Remove duplicates based on the content of two columns not the order

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a correlation matrix that i melted into a dataframe so now i have the following for example:

```
First      Second       Value
A          B            0.5
B          A            0.5
A          C            0.2
```

i want to delete only one of the first two rows. What would be the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#if want select columns by columns names
m = ~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['First','Second']], axis=1)).duplicated()
#if want select columns by positons
#m = ~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.iloc[:,:2], axis=1)).duplicated()
print (m)

0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool

df = df[m]
print (df)
  First Second  Value
0     A      B    0.5
2     A      C    0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could call [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) on the [`np.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html)ed columns:

```
df = df.loc[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.iloc[:, :2])).duplicated()]
df

  First Second  Value
0     A      B    0.5
2     A      C    0.2
```

---

**Details**

```
np.sort(df.iloc[:, :2])

array([['A', 'B'],
       ['A', 'B'],
       ['A', 'C']], dtype=object)

~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.iloc[:, :2], axis=1)).duplicated()

0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Sort the columns and figure out which ones are duplicates. The mask will then be used to filter out the dataframe via *boolean indexing*.

To reset the index, use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df.reset_index(drop=1)

  First Second  Value
0     A      B    0.5
1     A      C    0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also use following approach:

```
# create a new column after merging and sorting 'First' and 'Second':
df['newcol']=df.apply(lambda x: "".join(sorted(x[0]+x[1])), axis=1)
print(df)

  First Second  Value newcol
0     A      B    0.5     AB
1     B      A    0.5     AB
2     A      C    0.2     AC

# get its non-duplicated indexes and remove the new column: 
df = df[~df.newcol.duplicated()].iloc[:,:3]
print(df)

  First Second  Value
0     A      B    0.5
2     A      C    0.2
```